# Передача ArrayList<> из Activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Передаю ArrayList из MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public static final String INFO_ACTIVITY = "activity.info";
ArrayList<String> countriesArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
ArrayList<String> checkedCountries = new ArrayList<>();
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    initializeCountries();
    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, countriesArrayList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            SparseBooleanArray booleanArray = listView.getCheckedItemPositions();
            for (int i = 0; i < countriesArrayList.size(); i++) {
                if (booleanArray.get(i)) {
                    checkedCountries.add(countriesArrayList.get(i));
                }
            }
        }
    });
}

private void initializeCountries() {
    countriesArrayList.add("Argentina");
    countriesArrayList.add("Brazil");
    countriesArrayList.add("Sweden");
    countriesArrayList.add("Japan");
}

public void onShow(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(INFO_ACTIVITY);
    intent.putExtra("countries", checkedCountries);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Принимаю ArrayList  в CountryInfoActivity

```
public class CountryInfoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_country_info);

    LinearLayout linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);

    ArrayList<String> chosenCountries = getIntent().getStringArrayListExtra("countries");
    assert chosenCountries != null;


    for (String country : chosenCountries) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        switch (country) {
            case "Argentina":
                textView.setText(R.string.argentinaInfo);
                break;
            case "Brazil":
                textView.setText(R.string.brazilInfo);
                break;
            case "Sweden":
                textView.setText(R.string.swedenInfo);
                break;
            case "Japan":
                textView.setText(R.string.japanInfo);
                break;
        }
        linearLayout.addView(textView);
    }
  }
}
```

Выдает ошибку NullPointerException во второй Activity в методе getStringArrayListExtra()
Где я ошибся?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Странно, но замена putExtra() на putStringArrayListExtra () помогло..